# How to resolve Java out of bounds coding error?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, bluej

I am trying to create a Times Tables quiz on BlueJ using Java and every time I try and run this code it tells me that there is an out of bounds exception and highlights the starred line of code.

```
public void getQuestion()
{
    boolean newQuestion;

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = 0;
    for (int j=1; j<=12; j++)
    {
        newQuestion=false;
        int i=0;
        while (newQuestion==false)
        {
            randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(12);
            randomInt = randomInt + 1;
            while ((chosenArray [i]!=randomInt) && (chosenArray[i]!= randomInt))
            {
                i=i+1;
                ***if (chosenArray[i]==0)***
                {
                    newQuestion = true;
                    chosenArray[i]=randomInt;

                }

            }

        }

    }
    System.out.print(timesTableChosen + " x " + randomInt + " = "); 
}
```

}

How should I resolve this so that it works?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us exception trace

Comment: `(chosenArray [i]!=randomInt) && (chosenArray[i]!= randomInt)` Why do you check that twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is that you overindex when increasing `i`, Use modulo operator `%` :

```
i=(i+1) % 12;
```

BTW, instead of magic numbers, like `12`, I'd use `chosenArray.length`, always.

Comment: This might end up in an infinite loop. But it solves the current problem.

Comment: @Tom yes, there are many problems with this code, but I do not volunteer to fix them all (and that wasn't asked, either)

Comment: @Tom about the infinite loop: if `chosenArray.length` is at least 12, it's not infinite loop.

Comment: @GaborSch It has nothing to do with the length. OP had the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because `(chosenArray [i]!=randomInt)` remained true and if he changes his code as you suggested, he'll check all twelve values over and over again. He should make sure, that the values in his `chosenArray` array are in range of 1 to 12 (inclusive) only.